# sed to replace a character from a column with space but retianing the format

Tags: replace, sed, awk, space

I have a file a.pdb as

```
ATOM   3201  CD2 LEU A 337       7.734  18.538   6.979  0.00  0.00     0.000 C 
ATOM   3202  C   LEU A 337       5.169  14.358   7.663  0.00  0.00     0.206 C 
ATOM   3203  O   LEU A 337       4.123  14.537   8.395  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
ATOM   3204  OXT LEU A 337       5.124  13.563   6.672  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
HETATM 3206  CA  CA  A 338      18.241  31.994  15.308  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA 
HETATM 3207  CA  CA  A 339      16.703  30.240  22.272  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA
```

Desired output:

```
ATOM   3201  CD2 LEU   337       7.735  18.538   6.979  0.00  0.00     0.000 C 
ATOM   3202  C   LEU   337       5.169  14.358   7.663  0.00  0.00     0.206 C 
ATOM   3203  O   LEU   337       4.122  14.537   8.395  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
ATOM   3204  OXT LEU   337       5.124  13.562   6.671  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
HETATM 3206  CA  CA    338      18.242  31.994  15.307  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA
HETATM 3207  CA  CA    339      16.703  30.240  22.272  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA
```

How can I replace the letter "A" in the 22nd column or 5th block with space  but retaining the format of a.pdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{21})A/\1 /' a.pdb
```

`(.{21})` matches 21 characters and put them in capture group 1, which is then used in the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$0=substr($0,1,21) FS substr($0,23)' file
```

```
$ awk '$0=substr($0,1,21) FS substr($0,23)' file
ATOM   3201  CD2 LEU   337       7.734  18.538   6.979  0.00  0.00     0.000 C 
ATOM   3202  C   LEU   337       5.169  14.358   7.663  0.00  0.00     0.206 C 
ATOM   3203  O   LEU   337       4.123  14.537   8.395  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
ATOM   3204  OXT LEU   337       5.124  13.563   6.672  0.00  0.00    -0.646 OA
HETATM 3206  CA  CA    338      18.241  31.994  15.308  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA 
HETATM 3207  CA  CA    339      16.703  30.240  22.272  0.00  0.00     0.000 CA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` in `awk` to do this...

```
awk '{gsub("A"," ",$5); print}' a.pdb
```

Comment: But awk doesnt retain the format. I lost the spacing between blocks.

Comment: ah! you want them aligned as before ? I already see @Barmar has a better answer for you...